# Multi level dictionary error in c#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, keynotfoundexception

Im using the following code to make JSON

```
        FilterModel f = new FilterModel();
        f.FilterName = "EducationLevel";
        f.filterValue = new List<string>();
        f.filterValue.Add("BE");
        f.GroupName="Education";


        FilterDictionary d = new FilterDictionary();
        d.FilterValuse = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        d.FilterValuse.Add(f.FilterName, f.filterValue);

        FilterSelectModel ff = new FilterSelectModel();

        ff.Filters = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();

        ff.Filters[f.GroupName].Add(f.FilterName, f.filterValue);



        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ff);
        Response.Write(json);
```

but it shows an exception in the bellow  line

```
ff.Filters[f.GroupName].Add(f.FilterName, f.filterValue);
```

it shows the following error

> *The given key was not present in the dictionary*

What went wrong ? any one can help me

Comment: `ff.Filters[Education]` is not present .You are only initialize and try to get one key

Comment: @Dev.ArunCC so how can i make change it to work?

Comment: try the answer and let me know status of your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code:

```
ff.Filters[f.GroupName].Add(f.FilterName, f.filterValue);
```

To:

```
ff.Filters.Add(f.GroupName, new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() 
 { {f.FilterName, f.filterValue} });
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Check out this [How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531208.aspx)